# Pattern fill violin plots (vioplot package)

Tags: r, violin-plot

Is there a way to fill violin plots with different patterns when using `vioplot` package to create plots in R?

I have figured out how to change color using col as shown below. But I don't even know how to begin with hatching in vioplot.

```
vioplot(random_value, at = 0.5, add = T, h = 0.04, col = 'lightsalmon4')
```

I have used `density` and `angle` but those don't help.

Comment: please modify your question to include what you have tried so far in terms of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question just in case it might be useful to someone else later. It seems like `vioplot` package itself does not allow "hatching" or "texture" in the violin plot it creates. However, it seems like it can be achieved by making small changes to the default `vioplot` function to incorporate `density` and `angle` to the polygon it creates as the violin plots.

```
vioplot2 = function (x, ..., range = 1.5, h = NULL, ylim = NULL, names = NULL, 
    horizontal = FALSE, col = "magenta", border = "black", lty = 1, 
    lwd = 1, rectCol = "black", density = NA, angle = 45, colMed = "white", pchMed = 19, 
    at, add = FALSE, wex = 1, drawRect = TRUE) 
{
    datas <- list(x, ...)
    n <- length(datas)
    if (missing(at)) 
        at <- 1:n
    upper <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    lower <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    q1 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    q3 <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    med <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
    base <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
    height <- vector(mode = "list", length = n)
    baserange <- c(Inf, -Inf)
    args <- list(display = "none")
    if (!(is.null(h))) 
        args <- c(args, h = h)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        data <- datas[[i]]
        data.min <- min(data)
        data.max <- max(data)
        q1[i] <- quantile(data, 0.25)
        q3[i] <- quantile(data, 0.75)
        med[i] <- median(data)
        iqd <- q3[i] - q1[i]
        upper[i] <- min(q3[i] + range * iqd, data.max)
        lower[i] <- max(q1[i] - range * iqd, data.min)
        est.xlim <- c(min(lower[i], data.min), max(upper[i], 
            data.max))
        smout <- do.call("sm.density", c(list(data, xlim = est.xlim), 
            args))
        hscale <- 0.4/max(smout$estimate) * wex
        base[[i]] <- smout$eval.points
        height[[i]] <- smout$estimate * hscale
        t <- range(base[[i]])
        baserange[1] <- min(baserange[1], t[1])
        baserange[2] <- max(baserange[2], t[2])
    }
    if (!add) {
        xlim <- if (n == 1) 
            at + c(-0.5, 0.5)
        else range(at) + min(diff(at))/2 * c(-1, 1)
        if (is.null(ylim)) {
            ylim <- baserange
        }
    }
    if (is.null(names)) {
        label <- 1:n
    }
    else {
        label <- names
    }
    boxwidth <- 0.05 * wex
    if (!add) 
        plot.new()
    if (!horizontal) {
        if (!add) {
            plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim)
            axis(2)
            axis(1, at = at, label = label)
        }
        box()
        for (i in 1:n) {
            polygon(c(at[i] - height[[i]], rev(at[i] + height[[i]])), 
                c(base[[i]], rev(base[[i]])), col = col, density = density, angle = angle, border = border, 
                lty = lty, lwd = lwd)
            if (drawRect) {
                lines(at[c(i, i)], c(lower[i], upper[i]), lwd = lwd, 
                  lty = lty)
                rect(at[i] - boxwidth/2, q1[i], at[i] + boxwidth/2, 
                  q3[i], col = rectCol)
                points(at[i], med[i], pch = pchMed, col = colMed)
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (!add) {
            plot.window(xlim = ylim, ylim = xlim)
            axis(1)
            axis(2, at = at, label = label)
        }
        box()
        for (i in 1:n) {
            polygon(c(base[[i]], rev(base[[i]])), c(at[i] - height[[i]], 
                rev(at[i] + height[[i]])), col = col, density = density, angle = angle, border = border, 
                lty = lty, lwd = lwd)
            if (drawRect) {
                lines(c(lower[i], upper[i]), at[c(i, i)], lwd = lwd, 
                  lty = lty)
                rect(q1[i], at[i] - boxwidth/2, q3[i], at[i] + 
                  boxwidth/2, col = rectCol)
                points(med[i], at[i], pch = pchMed, col = colMed)
            }
        }
    }
    invisible(list(upper = upper, lower = lower, median = med, 
        q1 = q1, q3 = q3))
}
```

**USAGE**

```
set.seed(42)
x = rnorm(50,20,4)
vioplot2(x,density = 9, angle = 20)
```

[image]